# My computer is 16G, but wmic command show 33554432(32G), Why?

Tags: windows-7

My computer has 16G memory.

When I run `wmic memphysical get maxcapacity` it returns `33554432(32G)`

Is there an problem with that command?

Comment: what part of "get maxcapacity" don't you understand?

Answer (score 5):

The `maxcapacity` command is showing what Windows thinks is the absolute maximum your system can support, either due to processor or motherboard support. i.e. You are seeing your system *maximum capacity*.

It is not showing your maximum *fitted* memory.

I can tell this because I know for a fact my processor (an old i7) has a maximum support of 16GB, but I have 12GB of RAM fitted.  When I run that command I get

```
>wmic memphysical get maxcapacity
MaxCapacity
16777216
```

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249830/how-can-i-get-total-physical-memory-using-windows-cmd) the command you want to get your current physical memory is:

```
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Which returns

```
TotalPhysicalMemory
12841988096
```

Which is, as near as makes no difference, 12GB.

---

On a side note, it appears that `MaxCapacity` returns a value in *kilobytes* while `TotalPhysicalMemory` returns a value in *bytes*.